# SQLite: execute case-sensitive LIKE query on a specific query

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, case-sensitive

I want to run a `SELECT ... LIKE` query in SQLite that is case-sensitive. But I only want this one query to be case sensitive, and nothing else.

I know there is

> PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = boolean;

But that seems to change all LIKE queries.

How can I enable case-sensitive LIKE on a single query?

Examples:
I want a query for "FuN" to match "blah FuN blah", but not "foo fun bar".

(This is running under PHP using PDO)

I might be able to toggle that on, then off after the query but I can concerned about the repercussions that may have (efficiency etc). Is there any harm?

I don't have write access to the database.

(This is under Windows Server 2008)

I also tried `SELECT id, summary, status FROM Tickets WHERE summary COLLATE BINARY LIKE '%OPS%';` but that did not do a case-sensitive SELECT, it still returned results returns like *laptops*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not go the simple way of using

```
PRAGMA case_sensitive_like = true/false;
```

before and after each query you want to be case sensitve? But beware- case sensitivity does only work for ASCII characters, not Unicode which makes SQlite not fully UC-compliant at this time.

Alternatively, SQlite allows applications to implement the REGEXP operator which might help according to [www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html).

Comment: Well, what happens if another query is run at the same time via another process? If that gets changed to true and suddenly 10 queries get run by users, won't they all be case sensitive?

Comment: @JBurace, sqlite is embedded, so it executes in the process of your php scripts. Sqlite isn't a seperately running process which acts as a server, like mysql for example. So, most of the pragmas only affect the process that sets them.

Comment: So what if httpd/IIS/etc have say 4 child processes out there handling web activity, and child #1 runs a case sensitive search (which sets the pragma to true) and during that child #2 is another user doing a case insensitive search at the same time? Both childs have 2 different queries (one for the PRAGMA and one for the SELECT), totaling 4 queries.

Comment: @JBurace I think you didn't really understand chris. Your four child processes' connections to the database share no parameters.

Comment: @jthill: that's what I thought too

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 SELECT id, summary, status FROM Tickets WHERE summary GLOB \"*OPS*\";
```

there is no space between `*`and `OPS`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your answer for formatting, please check if that's what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to do a seperate check in your php code on returned value to see if they match your case-sensitive data.

```
$rs = mysql_query("Select * from tbl where myfield like '%$Value%'");


while($row == mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{

     if (strpos($row['myfield'],$Value) !== false)
     {
        $Matches[] = $row;
      }


 }

 print_R($Matches);
```

Comment: What if I'm not picking a specific field to compare against? (in regards to the `myfield`)

Comment: Give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Like if "tbl" has 20 fields I want to select from. Your example is only checking against 1 field in the PHP.

Comment: In that instance it would be quite cumbersome, are you planning on checking case-sensitivity against 20 fields?

Comment: The user can pick, so yes that could be possible. For example, searching for "UI" for projects about UI. This has to be case sensitive or else it would return an extreme number of results with "ui" in words. The user would pick to search in say Description, Comments, ProjectName, Comments, Creator, Title etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

SELECT YOUR_COLUMN
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE YOUR_COLUMN
COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE  '%YOUR_VALUE%'

Not sure what your collation set is on the column. I picked latin as an example. Run the query and change 'cs' to 'ci' at the end. You should see different results.

**UPDATE**

Sorry. read the question too fast. The above collation is for mysql. For SQLLite, you should be able to use BINARY which should give you case sensitive search.

ref: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation

Comment: The collation on the column is blank. I ran the query but it gave me `no such collation sequence: latin1_general_cs`

Comment: @Jburace, right. Sorry. That's what happens when one reads the question too fast. :) My bad - the answer I gave is for mysql. Let me update for sqllite too.

Comment: Okay I tried `SELECT id, summary, status FROM Tickets WHERE summary COLLATE BINARY LIKE '%OPS%';` and didn't work; it still returned case insensitive (results such as `laptop`).

Comment: Interesting. I thought BINARY is supposed to be case sensitive. Did you try to rule out other things (i.e. Like operator & '%'). Maybe instead of Like, try to do  "='OPS'" and see what it does.

Comment: That won't test anything though. `=` is already case sensitive. If I do `SELECT id, summary, status FROM Tickets WHERE summary = 'errors ON 3 laptops';` it returns nothing but if I change `ON` to `on` (correct match) it'll return the match.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that per column, not per query (which may be your case). For this, use sqlite [collations](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation).

```
CREATE TABLE user (name VARCHAR(255) COLLATE NOCASE);
```

All `LIKE` operations on this column then will be case insensitive.

You also can `COLLATE` on queries even though the column isn't declared with a specific collation:

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE name LIKE '%php%' COLLATE NOCASE
```

Note that only ASCII chars are case insensitive by collation. "A" == "a", but "Æ" != "æ"

SQLite allows you to declare new collation types with `sqlite_create_collation` and them implement the collation logic on the PHP side, but PDO doesn't expose this.

Comment: `All LIKE operations on this column then will be case insensitive.` But I'm looking for case sensitive?

Comment: Sorry for that. What about using `PDO::sqliteCreateFunction` to override the sqlite `LIKE` to a PHP logic?

Comment: I looked up documentation on that and found `This function is EXPERIMENTAL.` This is a live environment and I don't think I'd want to try that yet until it's stable.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERe field LIKE '%search_term%'
```

In this form the SELECT is case insensitive.

Comment: JBurace asked for case SENSITIVE query.